# the operation being requested was not performed because

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

I cannot seem to get Windows 7's task scheduler to work.  I have it set to run daily at 12:00pm and also run immediately if it missed a schedule.  I can run the task manually without issue.  It just doesn't run on schedule.  Either it doesn't even attempt to run or it will show the below error:

`the operation being requested was not performed because the user has not logged on to the network`

What I want it is for the task to run at 12:00pm daily.  If, at that time, I am not logged on or the computer is off or hibernating, I want it to run the task as soon as it is able.

I'll note that we have a Windows 2008 Server at work and scheduled tasks have never failed us.  100% reliable.  Not sure why Windows 7's task scheduler is any different

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have it to run only if you're logged in ("Run whether user is logged in or not"), hence the error message. You need to have it run whether you're logged in or not. If that doesn't work, try storing credentials. For me, I had the task run as Administrator, so it wouldn't even run manually (because, hey, the Administrator account is logged off).

Comment: So simple, yet this is exactly where I messed up. Thanks!